# Why does CV yield lower score?

Tags: cross-validation, multiclass-classification, prediction

My training accuracy was better than my test accuracy, hence I thought my model was over-fitted and tried Cross-validation. The model further degraded. Is that my input data need to be sanitised further and of better quality?

Please share your thoughts what could be getting wrong here.

My data distribution:
[image]
Code snippets...

My function `get_score`:

```
def get_score(model, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
    model.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())
    pred0 = model.predict(X_test)
    return accuracy_score(y_test, pred0)
```

Logic:

```
print('*TRAIN* Accuracy Score => '+str(accuracy_score(y_train, m.predict(X_train)))) # LinearSVC() used
print('*TEST* Accuracy Score => '+str(accuracy_score(y_test, pred))) # LinearSVC() used

print("... Cross Validation begins...")

y0 = pd.DataFrame(y)
y0.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

print(X.shape)
print(y0.shape)

kf = KFold(n_splits = 10)

e = []
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index],y0.iloc[train_index], y0.iloc[test_index]
    print(train_index, test_index)
    e.append(get_score(LinearSVC(random_state=777),X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test))

print("Finally :: "+str(np.mean(e)))
```

Output:

```
*TRAIN* Accuracy Score => 0.9451327433628318
*TEST* Accuracy Score => 0.6597345132743363
... Cross Validation begins...
(9040, 6458)
(9040, 1)
[ 904  905  906 ... 9037 9038 9039] [  0   1   2 ... 901 902 903]
[   0    1    2 ... 9037 9038 9039] [ 904  905  906 ... 1805 1806 1807]
[   0    1    2 ... 9037 9038 9039] [1808 1809 1810 ... 2709 2710 2711]
[   0    1    2 ... 9037 9038 9039] [2712 2713 2714 ... 3613 3614 3615]
[   0    1    2 ... 9037 9038 9039] [3616 3617 3618 ... 4517 4518 4519]
[   0    1    2 ... 9037 9038 9039] [4520 4521 4522 ... 5421 5422 5423]
[   0    1    2 ... 9037 9038 9039] [5424 5425 5426 ... 6325 6326 6327]
[   0    1    2 ... 9037 9038 9039] [6328 6329 6330 ... 7229 7230 7231]
[   0    1    2 ... 9037 9038 9039] [7232 7233 7234 ... 8133 8134 8135]
[   0    1    2 ... 8133 8134 8135] [8136 8137 8138 ... 9037 9038 9039]
Finally :: 0.32499999999999996
>>>
```

Edit -1- Adding values of "e"

```
[0.08075221238938053, 0.413716814159292, 0.05752212389380531, 0.15376106194690264, 0.14712389380530974, 0.4668141592920354, 0.6946902654867256, 0.7112831858407079, 0.33738938053097345, 0.18694690265486727]
```

Edit -2- Adding `shuffle=True` parameter to `KFold()`

Result:

```
[   0    1    2 ... 9037 9038 9039] [   4    5   10 ... 9007 9011 9024]
[   0    1    2 ... 9037 9038 9039] [  21   43   44 ... 9018 9035 9036]
[   0    2    3 ... 9037 9038 9039] [   1   20   60 ... 9023 9031 9034]
[   0    1    2 ... 9036 9037 9038] [   6   25   27 ... 9010 9025 9039]
[   0    1    2 ... 9037 9038 9039] [  15   16   28 ... 9029 9030 9033]
[   0    1    2 ... 9037 9038 9039] [   3   12   40 ... 9015 9017 9028]
[   0    1    2 ... 9037 9038 9039] [   7    8   23 ... 9013 9014 9027]
[   0    1    3 ... 9035 9036 9039] [   2   18   19 ... 9019 9037 9038]
[   0    1    2 ... 9037 9038 9039] [  24   37   39 ... 9012 9016 9026]
[   1    2    3 ... 9037 9038 9039] [   0    9   14 ... 9020 9021 9032]
[0.6504424778761062, 0.6736725663716814, 0.6969026548672567, 0.6692477876106194, 0.6769911504424779, 0.6382743362831859, 0.6692477876106194, 0.6648230088495575, 0.6648230088495575, 0.6814159292035398]
Finally :: 0.6685840707964601
```

Comment: Except for the first and last folds, test and train indices overlap, why? Also, check for the measure that you are reporting in two places, make sure that the same measure is reported in both places.

Comment: I don't think they overlap. Just the way they are split and printed, i guess. Note the difference between the first and last values in second array like (903-0), (1807-904), (2711-1808),..., (9039-8136). All equal to 903.

Comment: No, they don't. How are you so sure?

Comment: I think in train [0...9039], the test range [904...1807] is excluded. Just that it is not visible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91924/discussion-between-esmailian-and-ranit-b).

Comment: Could you report all ten values in e?

Comment: @Ben, I've added the values of "e" to the bottom of my post.

Comment: I would like to add one point (just realized) - The input data is sorted based on their output classes. Ex. say output class 'A' is set of records indices 1-40, class 'B' is record indices from 41-67, class 'C' is record indices from 68-118, etc. Should I take that with shuffle?

Comment: Wow! I just added `shuffle=True` parameter to `KFold()` and the prediction accuracy became 66.85%. I'll add details to bottom of my post.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, especially when I saw the wildly varying scores across folds.  I think you should post this as an answer.

Comment: Your comment above suggests you are doing multi-class classification. If that's the case then you should perform stratified cross-validation (i.e. use `StratifiedKFold`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, bradS. I didn't know about this concept. Let me explore that as well.

Comment: With stratification, each cross validation train set will be balanced (class proportion). In that way, the results will be more “real”

Answer (score -1):

Since your model performances worse on held-out data (validation or test), you have a high variance model.

The most common methods to lower variance are:

- Add more data to the training dataset.
- Increase regularization. Since you are using LinearSVC, that means [increasing C](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_scale_c.html).
- Switching to a bagged or boosted algorithms.